# OnScanCompletedListener crashing because of Toast

Tags: android, toast

I am writing to a SD card with in my class and i can successfully do that, I can also set a  MediaScannerConnection and also a OnScanCompletedListener. That all works but when i put a toast to alert the user that the scan has been complete in the OnScanCompleteListener i just get a lot of errors from the LogCat and the toast does not appear, but files still do save to SD card.

How can i solve this?

More detail below..

Writing to SD card  (Works perfectly)

```
  InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.greenball);
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
                is.read(data);
                os.write(data);
                is.close();
                os.close();
```

The OnScanCompletedListener, just doesn't work with the toast inside?. It still saves files on SD card, however i just get lots of errors from the Logcat and the toast in side the OnscanCompleteListener doesn't appear, I've tried it without the Toast and it works, so it must be that.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ExternalData.this,
new String[] {file.toString()},
null, 
new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Toast t = Toast.makeText(ExternalData.this, "scan complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                t.show();
                            }
                        });
```

Some of the Log Cat Errors

```
02-11 15:34:39.896: E/JavaBinder(11134): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create
handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

02-11 15:34:39.896: E/JavaBinder(11134):    at android.os.Handler.<init>   
(Handler.java:121)

02-11 15:34:39.896: E/JavaBinder(11134):    at 
android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
```

Any help would be great I've searched around and just cant find anything on this. Can some one correct me if its a simple error I've made, Thanks.

Here is my full code for this class just in case it helps:

```
 IMPORTS...

 public class ExternalData extends Activity implements OnClickListener, 
 OnItemSelectedListener  {

TextView canWrite, canRead;
String state;
boolean canW, canR;
Spinner spinner;
String[] paths = { "Music", "Pictures", "Download" };
File path = null;
File file = null;
EditText saveFile;
Button confirm, save;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.externaldata);


    canWrite = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCanWrite);
    canRead = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCanRead);
    confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bConfirmSaveAs);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSaveFile);
    saveFile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSaveAs);
    confirm.setOnClickListener(this);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);

    checkState();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ExternalData.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, paths);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


}

private void checkState() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        // read and write
        canWrite.setText("true");
        canRead.setText("true");
        canW = canR = true;

    } else if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
        // read but can't write
        canWrite.setText("false");
        canRead.setText("true");
        canW = false;
        canR = true;

    } else {
        canWrite.setText("false");
        canRead.setText("false");
        canW = canR = false;
    }

}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.bSaveFile:
        String f = saveFile.getText().toString();
        file = new File(path, f + "png");
        checkState();
        if (canW == canR == true){
            path.mkdir();
            try {
                InputStream is =    
      getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.greenball);
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
                is.read(data);
                os.write(data);
                is.close();
                os.close();

                Toast t = Toast.makeText(ExternalData.this, "File has been Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t.show();

                //Update files for the user to use
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ExternalData.this,
                        new String[] {file.toString()},
                        null, 
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Toast t = Toast.makeText(ExternalData.this, "Scan Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                t.show();
                            }
                        });


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        break;
    case R.id.bConfirmSaveAs:
        save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    switch (position){

    case 0:
        path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
        break;
    case 1:
        path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        break;
    case 2:
        path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        break;

    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are calling makeToast in the wrong thread.
Try to create an final handler and posting your makeToast.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile.....
    handler.post(new Runable()...
```

Comment: I don't know what that completely means since I'm quite new to android, but I've solved the problem, all i did is made the toast variables global and just initialized them once in the on Create method and then  the OnScanCompleteListener just had to show the toast. Do you think this is a ok fix?